# Replacing strings (from a list) with NaN in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a DataFrame `df` and a list of strings `colnames`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['a', 'foo', 'c' , 'bar'], 'bar': ['foo', 'b', 'c', 'bar']})

colnames = ['foo', 'bar']
```

I want to replace the words contained in `colnames` in my DataFrame `df` with 'NaN'. However, I only want to replace the values and not the column names. The output should look like:

```
    foo bar
0   a   NaN
1   NaN b
2   c   c
3   NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `replace`

```
df.replace(df.columns,np.nan)
   foo  bar
0    a  NaN
1  NaN    b
2    c    c
3  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
df.replace(colnames, np.nan)
```

**Output** :

```
   foo  bar
0    a  NaN
1  NaN    b
2    c    c
3  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Here `isin` and `mask`:

```
df.mask(df.isin(colnames))
```

Output:

```
   foo  bar
0    a  NaN
1  NaN    b
2    c    c
3  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use an index mask:

```
df[~df.isin(colnames)]
```

output

```
   foo  bar
0    a  NaN
1  NaN    b
2    c    c
3  NaN  NaN
```